# i want to integrate an Machine Learning system in my web app using Django Back-end from Nyckel Machine Learning Service?

Tags: django, machine-learning, post, postman, nyckel

i send the request to Nyckel Service and get the response back as text but the response i get is invalid format
i am working on implement image classification :

the result i need to get is this depends on the image i send it through the POST request for Nyckel Service :

{

"labelName": "harissa",

"labelId": "label_684pbumtvbzp3k9q",

"confidence": 0.76

}

@api_view(['POST','GET'])

def addProductByNyckel(request):

```
data = request.data


image = data['image']
url = 'https://www.nyckel.com/v1/functions/7aaigszss2ejx7t8/invoke/?format=json'
header = {
'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'
}

urlimg = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/chamia_2lJVXBC.jpg'


img = requests.get(urlimg,params=request.GET)
m = img.content

result = requests.post(url,m, headers=header)
dict = result.json() 

labelName= dict.get("labelName"),
labelId = dict.get("labelId"),
confidence = dict.get("confidence")

return Response(dict )
`
```

the error message is :

**{

```
"type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",


"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",


"status": 400,


"traceId": "00-983824a0cb2b204855f4387cf92f2dca-780a95630f9dc3d6-00",


"errors": {

    "$": [

        "'0x89' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."

    ],


    "input": [

        "The input field is required."

    ]

}
```

}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per nickle documentation you need to sent it via multipart request.

here is sample working request

```py
import requests
url = 'https://www.nyckel.com/v1/functions/7aaigszss2ejx7t8/invoke/?format=json'
file = open('/tmp/sharukh.jpeg', 'rb') # it has to be file content
result = requests.post(url, files={'data': file}) # posting multipart payload
dict = result.json()
print(dict, result.status_code)
```